# jquery incrementing from 0 to 100, then per 25

Tags: jquery

I have a button that increaes or decreases the value of an input by 25.
However, I would like it to skip the 25,50,75 steps, so it goes 0,100,125,150,...
I'm thinking this should be possible with an if statement on the increment, but unsure on how and where to implement it.

I'm also having some problems generalizing the code so I can use it with multiple input fields. I've tried combinations of e.target, event.target, this.. so far nothing has worked.

```
var element = $(this).siblings(':input');
var element = $(e.target).closest(".value");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aC45a/5/

This is the first time I've used jquery, and the markup confuses me, so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the corresponding input element, use `$(this).siblings(".value")`.

For skipping the numbers between 0 and 100, I use a conditional expression. I encapsulated it into a function for decrementing, because it's needed in both the initial click and the auto-repeat timer. This isn't necessary for the increment operation, because it's guaranteed that you'll be above 100 when the repetitions occur.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/aC45a/7/)

```
function dec25(oldval) {
    return oldval <= 100 ? 0 : oldval - 25;
}

$('.inc25').on({
    mousedown : function(e) {
        var element = $(this).siblings(".value");
        var oldval = parseInt(element.val(), 10);
        var newval = oldval == 0 ? 100 : oldval + 25;
        element.val(newval);

        timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
            interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                element.val(parseInt(element.val(), 10) + 25);
            }, 200);      
        }, 400);

        e.preventDefault();        
    },
    mouseup : function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
});

$('.dec25').on({
    mousedown : function(e) {
        var element = $(this).siblings(".value");
        element.val(dec25(parseInt(element.val(), 10)));

        timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
            interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                element.val(dec25(parseInt(element.val())));
            }, 200);      
        }, 400);

        e.preventDefault();        
    },
    mouseup : function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to start the first increment at 100.

```
increment = Math.max(100, increment + 25);
```

So in your code this would be...

```
element.val(Math.max(100, parseInt(element.val(), 10) + 25));
```

You can fix your multiple fields issue by using...

```
var element = $(e.target).siblings(".value");
```

Comment: Also note I've added the radix argument to the parseInt call, which is  good practice, to ensure it always parses in base-10.

Answer (score 0):

The incrementing is a javascript question, not jquery. I would handle it like this for incrementing:

```
value += 25;
if (value < 100)
    value = 100;
```

and like this for decrementing:

```
value -= 25;
if (value < 100)
    value = 0;
```

There are ways to condense the code further, but this is probably best for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/L3yUK/1/

I only adjusted the incremental function.

The relevant code:

```
$('.inc25').on({
    mousedown : function() {

        var element = $(this).parent().children(".value");
        var v = parseInt(element.val());

        element.val(v + (v>=100?25:100));
```

**element** is defined inside the mousedown handler.

$(this) points to the clicked element

$(this).parent() points to the parent div

$(this).parent().child(".value") dives back into the div for the element of class "value"

Get the actual value and store into a variable **v**

Then do your math/logic: increment v, how much ? if v>=100 increment by 25, otherwise increment by 100.